# Show that every irreducible representation of $SO_{3}$ is isomorphic to one of the representations $\Psi_{n}$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The question is given below:

[image]

And this is the mentioned exercise:

[image]

And this is 7.4:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Could anyone give me a hint about the solution of the question, I am stucked in it ?

Comment: You should formulate your question in a more concise way, and showing more efforts than posting a lengthy scan.

Comment: @YCor okay I will do this within 6 hrs ..... I am sorry

Comment: @YCor Sorry for being late ..... I have edited my question ...... shall  I edit it more or this is fine ? Actually I have a difficulty in understanding how we get $\Psi {n}$ from $\Phi_{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Vinberg book "Linear representations of finite groups "" has established the isomorphism between $SO_{3}$ and $SU_{2}/\{E, -E\}$ in pg. 76 Equation (4) and you can construct $\Psi_{n}$ from $\Phi_{n}$ with $n$ even from the last paragraph given in the question above and from Equation(8) mentioned in the question above. then use the second requirement that you have proved in question 7 to conclude what is required in question 9.